# The UFL 'u2lcom.dll' required to implement the function is missing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, rpt

I've been attempting to get my RPT to PDF conversion working via the REST API. I've scoured every possible thread on the internet. Is there someone who can precisely tell me what's wrong with the u2lcom.dll? It's present in the Explorer structure, and I even tried to register it, but no luck. "No entry point found...."

Currently, I'm working on:

Windows 11, 64-bit
Visual Studio 2022
.NET 4.8.0
Crystal Runtime Engine 13.0.34.4636 (64 and 32-bit installed).
I've also logged my dataset to check if it's empty, but all information is available.

Here is my code:

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
string reportFileName = @"C:\Users\user1\Source\Repos\project4\rptTopdf\Sample.pdf";
rpt.Load("C:/Users/user1/Source/Repos/project4/rptTopdf/Sample.rpt");

var cnn = new SqlConnection(testConnectionString);
cnn.Open();
var sql = selectStatement;

SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);

System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

dscmd.Fill(ds, tableName);

cnn.Close();
rpt.SetDataSource(ds);

rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, reportFileName);
```

Here is the stack trace:
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaException
HResult=0x80041A00
Message=Error in file "Sample 16288_6460_{71F8045C-A58F-4034-A6AD-5CF0E8CA2A1A}.rpt":
Error in formula Barcode128:
'WhilePrintingRecords;
'
UFL "u2lcom.dll" missing to implement the function.
Source=
Stack trace:

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Error in file "Sample 16288_6460_{71F8045C-A58F-4034-A6AD-5CF0E8CA2A1A}.rpt":
Error in formula Barcode128:
'WhilePrintingRecords;
'
UFL "u2lcom.dll" missing to implement the function.

I tried every Thread on the internet but had no luck with it

Comment: By the way, my workaround is to change the logic for the barcode. I am using Barcode 39 Engine now, not 128. Thats relevant because the titles error is the "default" error which includes like "every possible relevant case" for the Crystal Reports Runtime.